# the string '2016-07-29 23:57:10' is not a valid allxsd value

Tags: c#, web-services

I added a webreference to a webservice in Visual Studio 2013. Everything was create accordingly (WSDL, Reference.cs, etc)
But when I tried to consume one method I got the error: 
"the string '2016-07-29 23:57:10' is not a valid allxsd value"

Searching, I found solutions like add to my Reference.cs stuff like

```
[XmlIgnore]
```

And create another property to replace this one.
Other things also Didn't work out.
Any clue on how to solve?
I'm thinking to consume webservice manually, It's a better way?

P.s.: I added the reference as Service Reference also as WebService Reference. And change the culture en-US.

Comment: What is the corresponding WSDL or C# definition?  Where/Why did you change the culture?

Comment: I dont have WSDL here... Is in my work notebook... I change the culture because my application was in pt-BR (Brazilian portuguese) and the date format of this string en-US...

Comment: There is nothing en-US about this string

Comment: Anyway, with or without changing of culture same exception.

Comment: You can find the WSDL on the same URL as Add Service Ref. And you can find the generated C# (use F12 key)